# Ubuntu volume increase/decrease notification missing

Tags: pulseaudio, libnotify, ubuntu

The volume increase/decrease indicator went missing after installing pulseaudio and libnotify-bin. The brightness indicator is still working though. How do I get the volume notifier back in LUbuntu 14.04?

Image: http://postimg.org/image/wtu9etuk3/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps: it is how to add any icon launcher to the panel.

20180121 How to get #audio #icon back on #xfce Ubuntu panel

- Add a "launcher" icon:

  - Right-click the panel between the last window tab-item and the block of icons on the right-hand side
  - Select Panel."Add New Items" menu option
  - Add a "Launcher"
  - Use the "Panel Preferences"."Items" menu to move the new icon to where you want it, e.g. at the left of the right-hand-side block of icons
  - Close the panel properties dialog
- Configure the new launcher icon:

  - Right-click the new icon to configure it, select "Properties"."General" tab and use the "+" icon to add the new program
  - Scroll the list down to find the "PulseAudio Volume Control"
  - Close the dialog